# The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'idd' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new here to learn MVC. I struck on this error, I couldn't find the solution.

My Controller Look like this:

```
public class EmployeeDataController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Details(int idd)
    {
        EmployeeDataContext edc = new EmployeeDataContext();
        EmployeeData employee=  edc.employeedata.Single(emp => emp.id == idd);

        return View(employee);
    }
}
```

When executing the Details method from the browser (i.e. http://localhost:4166/EmployeeData/details/1) I get this error:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'idd' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Details(Int32)' in 'MvcDemo1.Controllers.EmployeeDataController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters

Any help would be great to solve my problem.

---

When i update my code and try to compile the program, there is no error at compile time but when i run the program that time i got an error

```
EmployeeData employee=  edc.employeedata.Single(x=>x.id==id);
```

**An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: An error occurred while executing the command Definition **

Comment: Try to replace `idd` with `id` in `Details` method

Comment: where do you call your `Details` method? That's the code to show

Comment: You need to show how you are calling the `Details()` method. Are you passing it a parameter named `idd` with a valid value?

Comment: It's telling you that you need to supply a value for `idd` when you invoke the `Details` action.  Do you supply a value?  How are you invoking that action?  What does the URL and/or form post look like?

Comment: I am calling it from  http://localhost:4166/EmployeeData/details/1

Comment: What do your routes look like in `RegisterRoutes`?

Comment: @wasimali: MVC doesn't by default map to any parameter called `idd`.  Did you add a route which does?

Comment: @david ..i didn't get you,Can you explain me

Comment: @wasimali: Well, the action expects a parameter called `idd`.  The URL you showed supplies a parameter (the value `1`), but MVC doesn't know to map that value to a parameter called `idd`.  You'd either need to update your route config to map it to that name, or specify the name manually in the URL (something like `?idd=1`), or change the parameter name to something mapped in the route config (likely `id`).

Comment: @wasimali, The default route has a parameter named `id` (see your `RouteConfig.cs` file). Change the parameter of the `Details()` method to `id` (not `idd`) and it will work, or else call the method using `/EmployeeData/details?idd=1`

Answer (score 5):

When you visit a URL such as `EmployeeData/details/1`, MVC will use your routes to map the controller, action method and parameters to use. By default the route you will have will look something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

With your URL, this says to take the `EmployeeData` as the controller, `details` as the action method and `1` as the value for the optional parameter with the name `id`. Your parameter is called `idd` so it's not mapped. As the parameter is marked as optional but it's non-nullable in your `Details` method an exception occurs.

You have three ways of solving this.

Firstly, you could change your route to use `idd` instead of `id`:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{idd}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", idd = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Secondly, you could change the parameter in your `Details` method to be called `id`:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)...
```

Finally, you could change the URL you are using to be explicit in the parmater being sent:

```
localhost:4166/EmployeeData/details?idd=1
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using default route config - than simply rename your action parameter to `id`:

```
 public ActionResult Details(int id)
 {
     EmployeeDataContext edc = new EmployeeDataContext();
     EmployeeData employee = edc.employeedata.Single(emp=>emp.id == id);

     return View(employee);
 }
```

Your parameter name `id` should exactly match one in the route config.